# Как передать данные из формы в базу данных. html, express, mysql

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express

Имеется html код с формой, а так же код для обработки POST запроса в app.js файле, и есть база данных (подключение к ней имеется). Необходимо, что бы данные из формы заносились в базу данных, но никак не выходит.

**index.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/test1/index.html" method="post">
    Введите имя:<br>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>

    Введите фамилию:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br>

    Отчество:
    <input type="text" name="sname" id="sname"><br>

    Email:
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>

    Номер телефона:
    <input type="text" name="numberphone" id="numberphone"><br>

    Должность:
    <input type="text" name="dolch" id="dolch"><br>

    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

````````````````````````````````````````````js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const urlEncodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
});

/* ``````````````` База данных ``````````````` */
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'practice',
  password: ''
});
/* ``````````````````````````````````````````` */

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('Ошибка: ' + err.message);
  } else {
    console.log('Подключение к базе данных успешно установлено');
  }
});

// Post запрос
app.post('/index.html', urlEncodedParser, function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body) return res.status(400);
  console.log(req.body);

  const fname = req.body.fname;
  const lname = req.body.lname;
  const sname = req.body.sname;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const numberphone = req.body.numberphone;
  const dolch = req.body.dolch;

  var sql = "INSERT INTO 'employees' ("
    + "fname,lname,sname,email,numberphone,dolch) VALUES("
    + "'" + fname + "',"
    + "'" + lname + "',"
    + "'" + sname + "',"
    + "'" + email + "',"
    + "'" + numberphone + "',"
    + "'" + dolch + "'"
    + ')';

  connection.query(sql, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('add');
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Work on port: 3000');
});
````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: в `action` у тебя прописан адрес, куда пользователь перенаправится при нажатии на кнопку submit. Метод `post` отправляет данные из формы. У тебя должен быть контроллер который замапит этот адрес и отправит полученные данные в БД.

Comment: прикладывайте код в виде текста, пожалуйста

Comment: @hot_penguin Благодарю. Не подскажешь, что необходимо прочесть по этому поводу, какую нибудь статью или т.п?

Comment: @ДмитрийТкаченко https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/4.5.php Здесь создан контроллер app.get(). В нем и нужно передать полученные данные в БД. Об этом прочитайте тут https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/8.6.php.

Comment: @ДмитрийТкаченко В самой форме есть инпуты и в них есть атрибут name. И чтобы сохранить в переменную введенные данные в какой-то инпут, нужно в контоллере прописать const name = req.body.name; где name - имя инпута (атрибут name="name"). А потом эти данные можно отправить в БД `pool.query("UPDATE users SET name=?, age=? WHERE id=?", [name, age, id], function(err, data) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);`